# How does the line "if @record.save" save a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've always been under the impression that to create and save a record, you have to run `record.new` and `record.save`, or `record.create`.

I've never understood how the record becomes saved in this code:

```
def create
  @record = Record.new(record_params)
  if @record.save
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

I removed the `if` line and the record stopped being saved. I thought `if` statements just tested conditions, or can they perform actions too?

Comment: `record.save` is `record.save`, regardless of how you use it or whether its part of a larger expression. `if record.save`, `x = record.save`, `return record.save`, `record.save if blah`, they all invoke `record.save` which saves the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the method `save` returns true or false after the method is called.
step 1, the model tries to save. if it saves, the records is saved and step 2, it returns true. if it does not save, the method returns false.  Your if statements controls what to do for each situation.

```
if @model.save
end
```

Answer (score 3):

> I thought if statements just tested conditions, or can they perform
>   actions too?

In Ruby, expression evaluation returns either truthy or falsey value, and it ***does not matter***, what the expression itself is.

The expression will be falsey ***exclusively*** if it returns either `nil` or `false`, otherwise it is truthy.

So, returning to your case, [ActiveRecord::Persistance#`save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) returns `true` if the record is successfully saved, otherwise `false`.

Comment: why removing -1? I would rather know, who you are.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby `if` is an expression (everything is an expression) that returns true or false. And just like any other language the contents of the `if` or `else` or `elsif` blocks are run.

When you place a predicate in the expression which has side effects (like saving a record to the database) the side effects are of course applied! This applies to most programming languages.

```
def foo
  print "Hello "
  true
end

if foo 
  print "world!"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby (and many other languages) `if` statement test the condition. But to test condition it must evaluate the code in the condition i.e. execute it.

So how it's doing there. `if` statement executes `@record.save`, `save` method tries to save `@record` and returns `true` if it did it successfully. If it cannot save the record it returns `false`.

Then `if` checks the result (`true` or `false`). `@record` saving is already performed by that time.

Answer (score 0):

Here `@record.save` will save the record and it will return either `true` or `false`

And that value will be evaluated by `if`

Normally you would use this when you want to do some actions on `success` or `failure` of record being saved